# Congruence and modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$228,547,866$ divided by $q$ leaves the remainder of $r$. Find $r+q$.
The problem is designated to be solved by using modular arithmetic. Even though I haven't learned what that is.

Comment: What is $t$ in this problem?

Comment: Do you have any extra assumptions on $q$?

Comment: It was r+q, edited

Answer (score 2):

$$228=r \pmod{q}\\547=r \pmod{q}\\866=r \pmod{q}\\547-228=0\pmod{q}\\319=0\pmod{q}$$
Now q can be either 11 or 29(prime factors of 319),and it can also be 319